# Like arbitrary, but for nonempty instead of inhabited

Tags: lean, lean-mathlib

I wrote some code that used a `[inhabited ι]` assumption, and then used `arbitrary ι` in the proof. The mathlib linter then complained

```
The following `inhabited` instances should be `nonempty`. argument 2: [_inst_3 : inhabited ι]
```

I can change the types as suggested, but what do I do with the `arbitrary ι` expression in my proofs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're seeing here is the behavior of the [`inhabited_nonempty` linter](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/find/linter.inhabited_nonempty):

```
import tactic

lemma foo {α} [inhabited α] : ∃ x : α, x = x :=
begin
  exact ⟨default, rfl⟩
end

#lint only inhabited_nonempty
/- Checking 1 declarations (plus 1 automatically generated ones) in the current file with 1 linters -/

/- The `inhabited_nonempty` linter reports: -/
/- USES OF `inhabited` SHOULD BE REPLACED WITH `nonempty`. -/
```

You can use the [`inhabit` tactic](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#inhabit) to solve this problem

```
import tactic

lemma foo {α} [nonempty α] : ∃ x : α, x = x :=
begin
  inhabit α,
  exact ⟨default, rfl⟩
end

#lint only inhabited_nonempty  -- All linting checks passed!
```

Note this has the advantage over `classical.arbitrary` of not introducing the axiom of choice:

```
#print axioms foo  -- no axioms
```

while being less cumbersome than the `nonempty.elim ‹nonempty α› $ λ a,` suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 6):

The most convenient option is `classical.arbitrary` (or `nonempty.some` if your `nonempty α` is an explicit ssumption rather than an instance one).

Note that this is exactly the axiom of choice. If your target is `Prop`, you can get away without using choice by writing something like `nonempty.elim ‹nonempty α› $ λ a, the_rest_of_your_proof`, which is arguably a bit cumbersome.